# Locating image by searching ID number

Tags: javascript

I need to locate an image by the image identification number.

How can I locate the image associated with identification number 1003_36776?

Comment: Where would you like to find that image? In your html document? What have you tried so far? A bit more info is needed to properly answer your needs.

Comment: I am using my iPhone to search for an image by the number showing for it as displayed on a laptop in the My Pictures folder.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest placing the image in a div or other container and using a data attribute to indicate the id, like so:

```
<div class="image-block" data-img-id="1003_36776">
    <p>Some descriptive text perhaps</p>
    <img src="1003_36776.jpg" alt="1003_36776">
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

This allows you to add related content to the image and should make it easier to control the presentation of the image.

The JavaScript can use **document.querySelector** to get to the img tag:

```
<script>
    var imgBlock = document.querySelector("[data-img-id='1003_36776'] img");
    document.getElementById("output").textContent = imgBlock.src;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess by identification number you mean html id. 
You can do it like this:

jQuery:

```
$("#1003_36776");
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("1003_36776")
```